# select value= json_encode($array) is not returning entire array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I tested the following:

```
<? echo json_encode($array) ?>    outputs: ["PG","Kevin Sad","8000","12"]
```

When I place it inside a form option value to be chosen by my script function:

```
<option value=<? echo json_encode($array) ?> > option1 </option>
```

When I click SUBMIT button and the following function fires from the script:

```
function submit_button(){
    var data=  player1.options[player1.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('print_result').innerHTML = data; 
}
```

only the following is outputted inside the div id="print_result" :

```
["PG","Kevin
```

Something happens with the space character " " that I cannot figure out..

I expected whole array to show up specifically including missing portion:

```
 Sad","8000","12"]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java nor JavaScript (yes, [these are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245069)) so I removed the tags. Anyway from what I remember values of attributes should be surrounded by quotes like `value="..."` or `value='...'` so try maybe with `<option value='<? echo json_encode($array) ?>'>` (I used `'` to avoid confusion with `"` which exist in actual value).

Comment: wow single quotes was the culprit!!  thanks so much!  sorry for wrong tags

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to escape the double quotes and/or you use single quotes to contain the JSON.

See example and how it effects the outcome.

```js
let options = document.querySelectorAll('option');
console.log(options[0].value, options[1].value);
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = options[1].value;
```

```html
<option value=["PG","Kevin Sad","8000","12"]> option1 </option>
<option value='["PG","Kevin Sad","8000","12"]'> option2 </option>
<div id="out"></div>
```